# C# Monotouch/Xamarin.iOS - Scrollable UIView

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, scrollable

If I have a `UIView` whose height is larger than the height of the `UIScreen`, and I fill it with other objects such as textbox's and label's. How do I make it so I can scroll through that entire view that contains all those other items?

Currently some of the items within that main `UIView` are off the screen at the bottom and I have no way of seeing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add scrollview and inside of your scrollview add your view.
and only need the content size of scrollview

```
 ScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (1000f, 100f);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) would be the solution.
A Nice tutorial to read:- http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: The problem with this is that it's a) in Objective C and b) Uses the interface builder, whereas I do everything programmatically....Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can also do the same programmatically.